# "Not Supported by this Version of Xcode” and After Update Xcode Raises "Unsupported Swift Version"

Tags: swift, xcode

After updating iPhone to iOS 12.2 I encountered this error in Xcode 10.1:

> “This iPhone is running iOS 12.2, which may not be supported by this
>   version of Xcode.”

So I have to update Xcode to latest version and after updating Xcode to 10.2, when I open the project, Xcode show another error that say:

> Unsupported Swift Version
>
> “MyProject” contains source code developed with Swift 3.x. This version of Xcode does not support building or migrating Swift 3.x
>   targets.
>
> Use Xcode 10.1 to migrate the code to Swift 4.

Now I couldn't run the project correctly in neither Xcode 10.1 nor 10.2!

I think I have to update my code to Swift 5 to Xcode 10.2 be able to compile the code. Am I right?

But updating the whole project is overwhelming.

Is there any other way to resolve the problem?

Comment: If you are using Xcode 10.2 you need to update your code

Answer (score 4):

The situation is neither dire nor daunting. All you really have to do is open the project with Xcode 10.1, mark the code as Swift 4, and close the project again. It would be good to *migrate* the code to Swift 4, though you don't have to; if you do, you certainly don't have to run it on a device — all you need to do is compile it as valid Swift 4. And the migrator will help you do that.

You will then be able to open the project in Xcode 10.2 and proceed however you like. Optimally you would then migrate *again*, to Swift 5, but you can postpone that step if you like.

> But updating the whole project is overwhelming.

That is a matter of opinion, really. And after all, you got yourself into this situation by not migrating out of Swift 3 earlier (you have had literally *years* to do that, but you didn't), and by updating the system on your device.

> Is there any other way to resolve the problem?

Not given your specifications. If you wish to run on this device that you have updated, you must update to Xcode 10.2, and you can do that only if you migrate out of Swift 3, which you can do with Xcode 10.1.

Comment: After changing "Swift Language Version" to Swift 5 and updating my code to swift 5, Xcode again says "Unsupported Swift Version ...". What's the problem?

Comment: There may be targets or frameworks that didn’t get updated? The error message doesn’t tell us where to look...

Comment: I updated all lines that had error for updating. But there are also some warning that say for example 'substring(with:)' is deprecated. Could it be the problem? Consider my project will be run, but Xcode at first says "Unsupported Swift Version"

Answer (score 4):

Open Xcode and change the project's Swift version to the latest (it'll say "unspecified").

[image: update project Swift version]

Also update your project's Build Settings `Library Search Paths` to include this at the top:

`$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift`

[image: Library Search Paths]

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue while migrating code from Swift 3.x to Swift 4+.x :

Try to check two main things :

1. Target and project setting swift version should be 4.2 or swift 5 ( in case of XCode 10.2)
2. change build system.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did it but Xcode again shows "Unsupported Swift Version" error.

Comment: Ok , so you have to go to XCode and select XCode menu, under it , there should be one option ToolChain , here you need to select correct swift version.